# problem in configuration laravel5.7 in centos7

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, centos7, php-7.2

I have Internal Server Error (error 500):

> [client 5.211.29.235:10910] /home/..../public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

`mysite.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /home/..../public_html/public/
ErrorLog /home/..../public/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Changing permission to read-write file(755) did not work.
Disable SELinux did not help.
Changing .httaccess also did not help.
changing `httpd.conf` did not help too.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride Options
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

change `.htaccess` did not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by changing `mysite.conf` file to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com
<Directory />
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /home/..../public_html/public/
ErrorLog /home/..../public/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```